# Как проверить отсутствие состояния aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, state

Всем привет пишу бота с помощью aiogram, и машины состояния. Проблема в том что при запуске бота командой '/start' у меня не работает проверка что state.proxy() data['t1'] уже существует.

В data['t1'] у меня храниться последнее время ответа бота, а по условию он не может отвечать чаще чем раз в 1 минуту. Получается так, что если пользователь будет постоянно писать '/start', бот будет отвечать сразу, без проверки на время.

Если пользователь первый раз пишет '/start', то бот должен ответить сразу, а если он уже писал '/start' и в state.proxy() data['t1'] есть какое либо значение, то сначала проверить время и только потом отвечать.

Нужно только добавить условие, которое будет смотреть существует ли вообще на данный момент state.proxy() data ['t1'] и какое в нем значение. Вот код:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

TOKEN_API = ""

storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

ikb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
ib1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Сгенерировать", callback_data='button1')

ikb.add(ib1)

ikb2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
ib3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Снова сгенерировать", callback_data='button2')

ikb2.add(ib3)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text='Чтобы сгенерировать нажмите кнопку ',
                           reply_markup=ikb)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if 't1' in state.proxy() > 0:  # проверка существования переменной t1. Здесь нужно изменить условие
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
        delta_min = datetime.now().minute
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['t1'] = delta_min  # записи текущего времени
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f'Твоё число ' + str(random.randint(1, 99)), 
                               reply_markup=ikb2)
        await callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup()



@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button2')
async def process_callback_button2(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        delta_min = data['t1']

        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, delta_min)
        if datetime.now().minute - delta_min >= 1:
            await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f'Твоё число ' + str(random.randint(1, 12)), reply_markup=ikb2)
            delta_min = datetime.now().minute
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data['t1'] = delta_min
            await callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup()

        else:
            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                                   f'Вы только что получили число\nЧисло можно получать не чаще чем 1 раз в 1 минуту, попробуйте позже')
            await callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup()
            await asyncio.sleep(60)
            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                                   f'Вам доступно новое число. Чтобы получить нажмите на кнопку', reply_markup=ikb2)
            await callback_query.message.edit_reply_markup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки наличия состояния можно использовать такой вариант

```
current_state = await state.get_state()
if current_state is None:
    # Состояния нет
```

Не уверен, что в вашем случае использование состояния для этого правильное решение. Я бы использовал [тротлинг](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/throtling_example.html)

Можете использовать такой декоратор для `process_callback_button1`

```
@dp.throttled(lambda msg, loop, *args, **kwargs: loop.create_task(bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Вы только что получили число\nЧисло можно получать не чаще чем 1 раз в 1 минуту, попробуйте позже")), rate=60)
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    ...
```

Либо вынести отправку сообщения в отдельную функцию

```
@dp.throttled(message_throttled, rate=60)
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    ...

async def message_throttled(*args, **kwargs):
    query = args[0]
    await query.message.answer("Вы только что получили число\nЧисло можно получать не чаще чем 1 раз в 1 минуту, попробуйте позже")
```